# Simplest way to transmit beep 5-10km (3-6 miles) using FM?

Tags: transmitter

I would like a simple device which enables me to transmit a beep every second or so on a chosen frequency.

Is anyone aware of a product that can do this?

If not, can anyone tell me what you would call this so I can work out how to make one? I have been searching for all sorts of terms, but I have no technical understanding of what I am trying to find.

Comment: How do you wish to generate the beep and the timing?  Would a simple handheld transmitter work for you?

Comment: Do you mean FM broadcast band (88-108 MHz) or FM modulation on some amateur legal band?

Comment: range is not defined by the transmitter alone, but by the power and "cleanness" of the transmitter, by the sensitivity of the receiver and noise and interference. See: Link budget. Without even giving band information, and saying which probability of detection is acceptable to you (nothing is **ever** 100% certain in wireless comms), we can't help you.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include more details of what you need, as mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

In the U.S., FCC regulations limit unlicensed broadcast-band FM transmission to a range of about 100 to 200 feet.  Read about Part 15 Devices here:
https://www.fcc.gov/media/radio/low-power-radio-general-information

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, but if you're talking about a Ham transmitter in the U.S. (and you're a licensed ham), then I'd look into the Ham shield for an Arduino.  It's a shield for an Arduino along with a (poorly documented) library that lets you control it.  With that you can program it to do pretty much whatever you'd like.